# What platform do I need for a Windows+Linux Web MVC API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono

I need to write a server application that replaces an existing solution. It's a server that accepts data from agents, processes it (filtering, database writing etc.), and passes it on to connected clients. The clients have been desktop applications, but should become web browsers now. So my goal was to use the .NET web technologies MVC Web Pages and MVC Web API to deliver the client GUI content to browsers (Web Pages) and accept data from the agents (Web API) through one common server layer.

The service must be able to run on Windows and Linux. Web hosting may be done through IIS or some sort of self-hosting on Windows. Not sure about the Linux side, probably self-hosting is the only viable option here.

The first problem is that I don't understand how the new DNX (ASP.NET 5) build thing is working. But I do know that Microsoft's Linux support is restricted to CoreCLR which is a very limited version. My server application must be able to do whatever the .NET Framework offers, so CoreCLR is probably not enough. So I guess I'd need Mono for the Linux side.

But Mono says it supports some of MVC 4 and nothing of MVC 5. Not to mention that the upcoming current version is MVC 6.

So can I use Mono at all in this scenario? Is it any help to use the new "vNext" project templates in Visual Studio 2015 (RC)? Or would it be better to stick with VS 2010 and MVC 4 (which is completely not-futureproof)? Or should I forget about the idea to use an HTTP interface for all communication and build my own TCP-based protocol which runs entirely outside of any ASP.NET context? (Serving clients is optional for Linux, but the agents must always be able to submit their data.)

Comment: 1) Mono does not cover .NET Framework either. 2) There are reports/posts claiming MVC 5 running fine on Mono 4. 3) MVC 6 must work on .NET Core as Microsoft will guarantee that, but not sure for Mono as no one will guarantee it. 4) Test on your own and stop when you hit problems you cannot fix. 5) Everything in this context is open source (even .NET Framework has many parts in reference sources now under open source licenses), so you can hack on them.